# How to do "cryptsetup luksOpen" and "mount" in a single command?

Tags: linux, mount

I currently have the following script. I run this manually when I need to mount the disk described. I don't need/want this disk auto-mounted on boot:

```
disk1="/dev/disk/by-uuid/84ea2a10-abcd-abcd-abcd-06deabcdabcd"
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen "${disk1}" disk1-crypt
sudo mount /dev/mapper/disk1-crypt /mnt/disk1
```

Is it possible to set up Linux such that it knows to automatically do the luksOpen command when I try to mount this disk? If possible, also luksClose when I unmount it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using systemd:

2. Add the LUKS configuration to `/etc/crypttab`, specifying "none" as the keyfile.
3. Add the mount configuration to `/etc/fstab` (probably specifying `noauto` as option).
4. Run `systemctl daemon-reload` to make it pick up the changes.
5. Use `systemctl start /mnt/disk1` to unlock and mount the filesystem.
6. Use `systemctl stop /mnt/disk1` to unmount the filesystem, which should result in the unlocked device being also stopped as unneeded.

If you're using GNOME (or have its components installed in general):

1. Use `gio mount -d /dev/disk/by-whatever` to mount the filesystem directly from its locked device. This does not accept a mountpoint location – if the disk matches crypttab & fstab entries it will honor those, but otherwise it will always default to `/run/media/USER/FSLABEL`.
2. Use `gio mount -u /run/media/ana/disk1` to unmount it.

Answer (score 0):

@user1686 shows the "right" way to do it under systemd, but for those without systemd (or who think systemd is too many complicated scriptlets tied together with glue!), just use @Gabriel's script and stick it in `/usr/local/bin/mount-my-disk`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $UID != 0 ]; exec sudo "$0" "$@"; fi

disk1="/dev/disk/by-uuid/84ea2a10-abcd-abcd-abcd-06deabcdabcd"
cryptsetup luksOpen "${disk1}" disk1-crypt
mount /dev/mapper/disk1-crypt /mnt/disk1
```

You probably don't want to give sudo access to all those commands or a user with `sudo mount` access might do something naughty: keep to the principle of least privilege.

The $UID check lets you enable sudo for only `/usr/local/bin/mount-my-disk`

Answer (score -1):

Not an elegant solution, but it may serve your use case (and it's definitely how I would solve it myself).

You can create a bash script that overrides the `mount` command as an alias, checking the arguments and doing what you need when that exact argument is passed, falling back to the actual `mount` command when anything else is passed.

Have a look at this script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

mount_disk1 () {
    disk1="/dev/disk/by-uuid/84ea2a10-abcd-abcd-abcd-06deabcdabcd"
    sudo cryptsetup luksOpen "${disk1}" disk1-crypt
    sudo mount /dev/mapper/disk1-crypt /mnt/disk1
}

[[ "$@" == "disk1" ]] && mount_disk1 \
|| mount "$@"
```

Here you have a function that does what you want. If the only thing you pass into it is `disk1` it will execute that function, else it'll execute the original `mount` passing all arguments.

You can put this script in a folder and set an alias in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` using

```
alias mount='<path to script>'
```

Then if you want to use the original `mount`, you can run `\mount` in the terminal.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ok, it would work, but as a systems administrator please never do this!  I don't want to spend an hour wondering why mount doesn't work as expected for some unconcieved reason only to discover that it was aliased!  A better option would be to put your script in /usr/local/sbin for that purpose.